# Invalid read and Leakage prevention in Valgrind

Tags: c++, visual-c++, valgrind

```
==7452== Invalid read of size 8
```

These are the above errors i am getting when I run the below code can any one let me know the appropriate cause for these errors.

```
     for(int r=1;r<=arasaraysizsase;r++) {
 48         ss = fmax(ss,u[i]);
 49         sa = fmin(sa,u[i]);
 50    }

 63     fasclosase(fasap);
 64     print_asamax(steasap);
 65 }
```

Comment: what is `step` ? Your have an extra `}` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Change `u[i]` to `u[i - 1]`, or change the loop to `for (i = 0; i < arraysize, i++)`.

Array indexes are *zero*-based in C++.

Comment: thank you for the reply I have an another problem can you please check the same

Comment: @user2830047: No, please don't do that. Don't change your question to something entirely different. Please roll back the change and post a new question.